# Can I pre-allocate a block of memory for C++11 std::tuple?

Tags: c++, memory, c++11

I have a user imputed string, say for example "5 6.3 foo 2.1". Each word or number in the string, like 5 or 6.3, can have a different type. I want to turn this user inputted array of characters into a tuple in the most time efficient way possible (in linear time). I do not know the number of words or numbers in the string, so I do not know in advance the number of elements that should be in the tuple. All I know is that the length of the tuple will be less than a pre-defined limit, let's say that it is 10000 elements. I believe that the std::tuple_cat function can be used to perform array-like concatenation and that I could use it to add each element to the tuple one by one. I don't like that idea because if std::tuple_cat works like array concatenation, then every element in the container will need to be copied over for each call to tuple_cat(n squared time). I would prefer if a memory space of say, for example, 100kb were reserved, or pre-allocated, for the tuple, and new elements added to the tuple were put into this pre-allocated memory space without having to copy over any other elements. Is there a way to turn my user inputted string into a tuple in linear time?

Comment: Trust me you don't want to do this, this is not what tuples are for

Comment: Yeah... I guess what I was actually looking for was a vector of elements of different types (int, double, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not really an efficient way to do what you want with an std::tuple. They are a compile time construct and you are wanting to determine the types in the tuple at runtime. The only way to do that would be to pre-instantiate every permutation of types up to your maximum number of elements, and that would be rather a large number...

Sounds like what you really want is something like a `std::vector<boost::variant<int, double, std::string...>>`.

Comment: The boost thing sounds like a good idea because I know that the input will be transformed into a finite number of distinct data types (about 8-ish). I'll look into it. Thank you.

Comment: On second thought, I'm having so much trouble learning and using boost::variant that I'm seriously considering giving each struct in my program an integer data member called "type" and then giving each type an enum value that corresponds with it. Then I would go "if (struct.type == 1) {//do something} else if (struct.type == 2) {//do something else}". I can't find a good tutorial, the one at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html isn't detailed enough.